# How can I return a value by matching date between date range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to look up date by date compared to dates in ranges from the start date to the end date?
criteria are countries and delivery date

[image]

I try to get the amount from COL_5 of the table service fee to match with country and delivery date

Comment: Your tags are confusing... Are you looking for php code or VBA code? Also is this for MS Excel or for Google Sheets?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this, the system suggested tagging somethings.  I promise to never tag things that are not related to the question again

Comment: No worries. Since you accepted an answer, I am assuming that you are looking for an Excel formula. I will update tags accordingly. If they are not the right ones then change it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the first is column "A",

the formula is an array formula, please use the hold shift before entering

{=INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MATCH(1,(D2>=$K$2:$K$10)*(D2<=$L$2:$L$10),0))}

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "use the hold shift"?

Comment: @NewLFC, I mean, hold the control+shift and press enter